# get all hyperlinks in array of uitextview in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, hyperlink, uitextview

I have a UITextView in which i have 5 hyperlinks and 5 phone numbers.How do i get all those hyperlinks and phone numbers in a NSarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html)'s `componentsMatchedByRegex:` method. You can then use a regular expression to find the appropriate parts of the text, and you'll get the results returned as an array.

You can use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to experiment with your specific regular expressions, and use the "Community" to find pre-built regular expressions that find phone numbers and hyperlinks. (They're there, I checked!)

RegexKitLite compiles right into your app, so there's no problem using it on the iPhone. Good luck!